# How to define $\delta$ to prove $\lim\limits_{x \to 9} \sqrt{x-5} = 2$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

When tackling this problem, parting from the assumption that $\lvert \sqrt{x-5} - 2\rvert \lt \epsilon$, I arrived through arithmetical manipulation at $$\frac{\lvert x-9\rvert}{\lvert \sqrt{x-5} + 2\rvert} \lt \epsilon,$$ which has the $\lvert x-9\rvert$ needed to prove that for a certain $\delta$, $0<|x-9|<\delta \Rightarrow |\sqrt{x-5} + 2|<\epsilon$.
However, I don't know how to eliminate the $x$ in ${\lvert \sqrt{x-5} + 2\rvert}$, such that I can define $\delta$ solely based on $\epsilon$. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Should the denominator be $|\sqrt{x-5}+2|$ instead?

Comment: @player3236 Yes, sorry about that, it was a typo.

Comment: In that case, do you see that the denominator must be larger than $2$? This will help you define your $\delta$.

Comment: Have a look at the examples on [this page](http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/DeltaEpsilonProofs03.htm). Once you find a suitable value of $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$, you need to compile what you have written into a proper proof.

Comment: @player3236 Oh I see, but that means that $\frac{|x-9|}{|\sqrt{x-5}+2|} < \frac{|x-9|}{2}$ right? But can I say that $\frac{|x-9|}{2} < \epsilon$?

Comment: If you choose an appropriate $\delta$. We have $\frac{|x-9|}2<\frac \delta 2$, and it can be less than $\epsilon$. Be careful though, you don't want $x-5$ to be able to be negative.

Comment: @player3236 Oh ok I think I understand it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $|x-9|<\delta$ we have
$$
\left| \sqrt{x-5} - 2 \right|
= \left| \frac{(\sqrt{x-5} - 2)(\sqrt{x-5} + 2)}{\sqrt{x-5} + 2} \right|
= \left| \frac{x-9}{\sqrt{x-5} + 2} \right|
< \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{x-5} + 2}
.
$$
Now note that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5} + 2} < \frac{1}{2}$ as long as $x-5>0.$ The latter can be achieved by making sure that $|x-9|<4.$ Therefore we will require $\delta<4.$ Then we can just take $\delta\leq 2\epsilon$ and we can continue:
$$
\cdots < \frac{\delta}{2} \leq \epsilon.
$$

Thus, given $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta=\min(2\epsilon,4).$

Answer (score 0):

Hints: For this particular problem , for convenient first we'll calculate the value of $\delta$ ,

We have $$|\sqrt{x-5}-2|<\epsilon$$

$$-\epsilon<\sqrt{x-5}-2<\epsilon$$

$$(2-\epsilon)^2-4<x-5<(2+\epsilon)^2-4$$.

Now choose $\delta=\text{min}\{(2-\epsilon)^2-4,(2+\epsilon)^2-4$}.

Comment: Where did the +4 come from on both sides of the final inequality?

Comment: That was typo now corrected.

Comment: Are you sure you've corrected it?

Comment: Oh I see, but shouldn't $(2-\epsilon)^2 - 4$ and $(2+\epsilon)^2 - 4$ be absolute values?

Comment: They don't have to be, since both are strictly positive always.

Comment: @player3236 but since $\epsilon$ is positive and arbitrarily small, isn't it possible that $(2 - \epsilon)^2 < 4$, therefore making $(2 - \epsilon)^2 - 4$ negative?

Comment: Yes. I missed that, sorry. It is always negative.

Comment: @player3236 Ok. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The third inequality should have $x-9$ in the middle. $\delta$ should be chosen as $\min\{4-(2-\epsilon)^2,(2+\epsilon)^2-4\}$

Comment: Yes, I had just noticed that $x - 5$, this makes more sense. Thanks!